# Is there min size of IMFSample when ProcessInput?

Tags: video, h.264, ms-media-foundation

- now I am using media foundation to process h264 data and it is live data.
- receive data by socket
- MFCreateMemoryBuffer to create IMFMediaBuffer and copy the data to the buffer
- MFCreateSample
- ProcessInput to pass the sample created.
- get outputData.

now my question is when I first receive data and ProcessInput it is all right.
but then I will receive some small data (may be only 3kb?) and the image is not right and will lack something(only part of the whole right image).

so I think it does not receive the whole data needed to to IMFTransform so I will keep the data until it is 30kb(or other larger) and then go to MFCreateMemoryBuffer.

yes now the image frame is right until the last frame.

so I guess I do not get the whole right data of one Frame right?
how to get the right size of one completely IMFSample(Frame)?

I do as @Simon Mourier 's code but there is error image.
[image]

Comment: You setup the transform (format, sizes, etc.) so you're supposed to know the sample input size, or more generally what you give as input. Can you clarify your question?

Comment: @SimonMourier maybe I ask it wrong. what I want to ask is that the size(min) of the buffer data. the h264 is compressed as you know. and If I changed nothing(desktop not changed and mouse not moved) the image Frame is same with before frame. there will be no data right? If I move the mouse very tightly there will be very tiny size of h264 data . and I will receive it and then pass it to ProcessInput as parameter and I can not get the right output Frame unless I wait some more data

Comment: Ok so if you're *decoding* H264 frames, then you don't have to process input samples of specific size (it's compressed input) just feed the chunks of data you have and make sure you handle the HRESULT from `ProcessInput` (eg continue if `MF_E_NOTACCEPTING`) & `ProcessOutput` (eg: continue if `MF_E_TRANSFORM_NEED_MORE_INPUT`) carefully.

Comment: thank you @SimonMourier .
as what you said should I Add data to the first sample 's buffer when processOutputResult == MF_E_TRANSFORM_NEED_MORE_INPUT?

Comment: Yes, for each chunk of data (ie random number of bytes), create one sample with one buffer with the bytes, while you receive this `MF_E_TRANSFORM_NEED_MORE_INPUT`.

Comment: while I receive this `MF_E_TRANSFORM_NEED_MORE_INPUT` I feed data to the one sample and one buffer and no need to create more sample. is I understand it right?
and there will be no `MF_E_TRANSFORM_NEED_MORE_INTPUT` again

Comment: I can provide some sample C++ code if you want

Comment: @SimonMourier you said create one sample with one buffer.  you mean I need to create one sample with one buffer when I receive MF_E_TRANSFORM_NEED_MORE_INPUT and then ProcessInput? or just create IMediaBuffer to AddBuffer to the first sample?

Comment: @SimonMourier I add buffer(MFCreatememoryBuffer) to the first IMFSample and nothing changed there is still `MF_E_TRANSFORM_NEED_MORE_INPUT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample code that decodes an H264 stream of bytes using Media Foundation [H.264 Video Decoder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/h-264-video-decoder) transform.

It simulates the stream of various-sized chunks of bytes using a file but the principles are the same.

Key points:

- You can feed chunks with any number of bytes as input to the transform
- The transform needs fixed-sized output samples
- The transform cannot allocate samples by itself
- Initially nobody knows the samples required size, so we have to feed the transform with bytes until it tells us what the samples size must be.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <mfapi.h>
#include <mferror.h>
#include <mfidl.h>
#include <mftransform.h>
#include <cstdlib>

#pragma comment(lib, "mfplat.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "mfuuid.lib")

#define HRCHECK(__expr) {auto __hr=(__expr);if(FAILED(__hr)){wprintf(L"FAILURE 0x%08X (%i)\n\tline: %u file: '%s'\n\texpr: '" _CRT_WIDE(#__expr) L"'\n",__hr,__hr,__LINE__,_CRT_WIDE(__FILE__));_CrtDbgBreak();}}
#define WIN32CHECK(__expr) {if(!(__expr)){auto __hr=HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());{wprintf(L"FAILURE 0x%08X (%i)\n\tline: %u file: '%s'\n\texpr: '" _CRT_WIDE(#__expr) L"'\n",__hr,__hr,__LINE__,_CRT_WIDE(__FILE__));_CrtDbgBreak();}}}

static HRESULT SetOutputType(IMFTransform* transform, GUID format)
{
    DWORD index = 0;
    do
    {
        CComPtr<IMFMediaType> outputType;
        auto hr = transform->GetOutputAvailableType(0, index++, &outputType);
        if (FAILED(hr))
            return hr;

        GUID guid;
        if (SUCCEEDED(outputType->GetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, &guid)) && guid == format)
        {
            HRCHECK(transform->SetOutputType(0, outputType, 0));
            return S_OK;
        }
    } while (true);
}

int main()
{
    HRCHECK(CoInitialize(nullptr));
    {
        HRCHECK(MFStartup(MF_VERSION));
        // open file
        auto file = CreateFile(L"h264.h264", GENERIC_READ, 0, nullptr, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, nullptr);
        WIN32CHECK(file != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);

        // create H264 transform https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/h-264-video-decoder
        CComPtr<IMFTransform> decoder;
        HRCHECK(decoder.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_MSH264DecoderMFT));

        // You can check in decoder attributes that MF_MT_FIXED_SIZE_SAMPLES is set to TRUE.
        // Calling GetOutputStreamInfo this will tell you the MFT cannot provide samples
        // as MFT_OUTPUT_STREAM_CAN_PROVIDE_SAMPLES and MFT_OUTPUT_STREAM_PROVIDES_SAMPLES are not set

        // So we don't know enough information yet, we'll feed input samples until we get MF_E_TRANSFORM_STREAM_CHANGE and then we'll provide a sample as per doc:
        //   "If the input type contains only these two attributes, the decoder will offer a default output type, which acts as a placeholder."
        //   "When the decoder receives enough input samples to produce an output frame, it signals a format change by returning MF_E_TRANSFORM_STREAM_CHANGE"
        UINT32 sampleSize = 0;

        // input type is H264
        CComPtr<IMFMediaType> inputType;
        HRCHECK(MFCreateMediaType(&inputType));
        HRCHECK(inputType->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video));
        HRCHECK(inputType->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFVideoFormat_H264));
        HRCHECK(decoder->SetInputType(0, inputType, 0)); // video is id 0

        // get (and set) NV12 output type (could be I420, IYUV, YUY2, YV12)
        HRCHECK(SetOutputType(decoder, MFVideoFormat_NV12));

        do
        {
            // get a random chunk size between 500 and 1500
            DWORD chunkSize = 500 + (1000 * (RAND_MAX - std::rand())) / RAND_MAX;

            // create an MF input buffer & read into it
            CComPtr<IMFMediaBuffer> inputBuffer;
            HRCHECK(MFCreateMemoryBuffer(chunkSize, &inputBuffer));
            BYTE* chunk;
            HRCHECK(inputBuffer->Lock(&chunk, nullptr, nullptr));
            DWORD read;
            WIN32CHECK(ReadFile(file, chunk, chunkSize, &read, nullptr));
            HRCHECK(inputBuffer->SetCurrentLength(read));
            HRCHECK(inputBuffer->Unlock());
            if (read)
            {
                CComPtr<IMFSample> inputSample;
                HRCHECK(MFCreateSample(&inputSample));
                HRCHECK(inputSample->AddBuffer(inputBuffer));

                auto hr = decoder->ProcessInput(0, inputSample, 0);
                if (hr != MF_E_NOTACCEPTING) // just go on
                {
                    HRCHECK(hr);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // end of file, ask decoder to process all data from previous calls
                HRCHECK(decoder->ProcessMessage(MFT_MESSAGE_COMMAND_DRAIN, 0));
            }

            CComPtr<IMFSample> outputSample;
            HRCHECK(MFCreateSample(&outputSample));
            MFT_OUTPUT_DATA_BUFFER outputBuffer{};
            outputBuffer.pSample = outputSample;

            if (sampleSize)
            {
                // now we know the size so we can (and must) allocate the MF output buffer
                CComPtr<IMFMediaBuffer> outputBuffer;
                HRCHECK(MFCreateMemoryBuffer(sampleSize, &outputBuffer));
                HRCHECK(outputSample->AddBuffer(outputBuffer));
            } // else just continue to process

            DWORD status = 0;
            auto hr = decoder->ProcessOutput(0, 1, &outputBuffer, &status);
            if (hr == MF_E_TRANSFORM_NEED_MORE_INPUT) // just go on
            {
                if (!read) // file is all read
                    break;

                continue;
            }

            // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/handling-stream-changes
            if (hr == MF_E_TRANSFORM_STREAM_CHANGE)
            {
                // get (and set) NV12 output type (could be I420, IYUV, YUY2, YV12)
                HRCHECK(SetOutputType(decoder, MFVideoFormat_NV12));

                // now get the sample size
                CComPtr<IMFMediaType> type;
                HRCHECK(decoder->GetOutputCurrentType(0, &type));
                HRCHECK(type->GetUINT32(MF_MT_SAMPLE_SIZE, &sampleSize));
                continue;
            }
            HRCHECK(hr);

            LONGLONG time, duration;
            HRCHECK(outputSample->GetSampleTime(&time));
            HRCHECK(outputSample->GetSampleDuration(&duration));
            wprintf(L"Sample time: %I64u ms duration: %I64u ms\n", time / 10000, duration / 10000);
        } while (true);

        // close file
        CloseHandle(file);
        HRCHECK(MFShutdown());
    }
    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

Full project is available here https://github.com/smourier/MFDecodeH264

Comment: thank you I do as your code. but there is not right image.

Comment: -1.the first time I create IMFSample and Lock 5mb data it goes well.
-2.and wait for 5(or other) seconds and I send another packet of data. it is goes not right.
-3. I use VideoProcessor to process NV12 data to rgb. is it right? what way do you suggest me to process the NV12 data? 

thank you very much !!!

Comment: Using video processor to convert NV12 to RGB is fine, but for the rest, I cannot say w/o some reproducing code.

Comment: thank you . and the last question please : can directx display yuv(nv12) directly? or I have to convert it to rgb?

Comment: No you'll need to convert, using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/colorconverter or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/video-processor-mft for example